# Visual Studio 2017 cmake project : how to build two target in single step

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am building a cmake application using Visual studio 2017 which needs to build some part/some files on linux machine while some needs to be build on windows and for that I am using WSL.

Now point is, to build windows part I have target "x64-Debug" and for linux part target is "Linux-Debug" so my point is I want to build this both configuration in single build step.
Is there any way , i can use something like post build of cmake which will trigger second project build.

How to run post build step in cmake project.

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you are suggesting. You can try [Cross Compiling](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling). However, that comes with it's own set of headaches. Since you already have WSL, I think cross-compiling is not the way to go.

If you really want to automate the process, then you'll want to use a build automation server (e.g. Jenkins). If you have an open-source project, I would suggest using [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/) and [Appveyor](https://travis-ci.org/).